# How to run my Java EE project on bare machine?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have made a medical project in java technology. I'm using the Apache Tomcat server and Oracle 10g as a database.

I want to run this project on a *bare machine*. I mean when I switched on my PC both Tomcat and Oracle server get instantiated and the homepage of my project gets opened.

Comment: "bare machine" doesn't mean what you just asked. It sounds more like you want to have your PC act as a server and have those service start up on boot. The instructions for running these as services is included in the respective documentation.

Comment: I don't believe those software packages are designed to run without an operating system.  It sounds more like you want to autorun things, or hide the usual operating system UI in some kind of kiosk mode.

Comment: Yap, you are right. I want to hide OS UI.

Ummm....what is this kiosk mode....Plz explain

Is their any other option to get this work done???

Answer (score 0):

Is machine Windows, Unix, other? If windows, u will want to configure a windows service. As stated above, such methods are well documented in the respective applications.